# Android file picker returns different types of uri

Tags: android, kotlin

When I am using android file picker I am getting 2 different types of URI as mentioned below:

`content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A51`
(I get this when I select the file from the file picker option marked in blue circle in the attached screenshot)
and

`content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2FKTM%20DUKE%20Range%20E-Brochure%202022.pdf`
(I get this when I select the file from the file picker option marked in green circle in the attached screenshot)

[image: File picker screnshot]

Simply put, one uri has the file name the other one does not. How do I make sure that I get the file name from both options or at least restrict it to the second type of uri?

Following is the code that opens the intent

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
intent.type = "*/*"
selectFilesActivityResult.launch(intent)
```

Comment: The simplest is to make a DocumentFile instance for the obtained uri and then use documentFile.getName(). Have a look at DocumentFile.fromSingleUri() (or something like that).

Comment: You cannot restrict to a 'type' of uri. You got uries from different content providers. You cannot just change the provider. (Dont call it type).

Comment: ACTION_GET_CONTENT can give you uris of many different content providers.

Answer (score 0):

I found out another way to get the file name as described in the official documentation [Examine document metadata](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#examine-metadata). Now I am able to get the name irrespective of where the user chooses the file from.